# Google Analytics API TotalEvents query

Tags: google-analytics-api

I'm trying to get a total count for a give event,however I get a number much bigger(10-20 times bigger), than I see on the GA website,  what am I doing wrong? (api v3)

here is the segment

**metric:**

```
ga:totalEvents
```

**segment:**

```
dynamic::ga:eventCategory==mycategory;ga:eventAction==myaction;ga:eventLabel==mylabel
```

note that I get wrong results with the query explorer as well.

Comment: and what is the report you're looking at in the Web Interface? What if you create a custom report in the web interface, do you get the same results?

Comment: a custom report returns the right results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a segment instead of a filter.

Segments are session based so it will include all events in a session if it matches you specification. So essentially if I triggered the event you want plus other events they will all be included in the total events field.

What you need to do Is remove the segment and add a filter, the filter will include only the data you request.

Hope that helps

Comment: I'll test that tomorrow, I guess it will work.but why using segment includes all the event of that session? Event is a hit dimension not a session nor a user

Comment: Hi, Yes events are hit based, But segments are session based, so essentially if you are using segments you have to keep in mind that if I trigger an event, that hit based event will be associated to my session on the site. your example above was using a metric to show the total number of events on the site, but segmented to include people who had interacted with a specific event, Now when on you site, i might trigger many different events including the one you want, all of these will be included because the segment is session based.