# Why does google analytics not segment when using != operator?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am playing around with Google analytics and for some reason can't get dynamic::ga:eventAction expressions to work correctly:

They both yield the same results, 348 clicks.

Both != and == yield the same results, see below:

[image: How not equal looks]

[image: How equal equal looks]

Comment: Are you sure about "==" ? In the documentation for the core reporting api it's a single "=".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no error, what actually happened is that you used a segment instead of a filter which is why you're seeing both data. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19984057/google-analytics-api-totalevents-query).

Segments only separate data and do not filter out anything.

Hope that helps. :)